# Why are empty org.eclipse.persistence messages being logged on application startup?

Tags: logging, eclipselink, jboss7.x

### Using

- EclipseLink 2.4.1
- JBoss AS 7.1.1

### Problem

I have developed a servlet that uses EclipseLink for persistence.

When the application is starting I get the following message in the server log repeated many times:

```
12:17:45,586 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence.metadata] (MSC service thread 1-1) Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [CategoryCode] for the entity class [class se.magos.domain.Site] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
12:17:45,825 INFO  [org.eclipse.persistence.connection] (MSC service thread 1-1) vfs:/C:/Dev/Applications/JBoss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Ear.ear/Persistence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/_foo login successful
12:17:45,891 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence] (MSC service thread 1-1)
12:17:45,894 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence] (MSC service thread 1-1) 
12:17:45,896 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence] (MSC service thread 1-1) 
12:17:45,898 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence] (MSC service thread 1-1) 
12:17:45,900 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence] (MSC service thread 1-1) 
...and it goes on and on...
12:17:46,091 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence] (MSC service thread 1-1) 
12:17:46,093 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence] (MSC service thread 1-1) 
12:17:46,097 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence] (MSC service thread 1-1) 
12:17:46,236 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

It's close to the count of domain and service objects and combined but not exact.

What can be the reason for this log message and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS 7 does not use EclipseLink as it's JPA implementation. It uses Hibernate by default. There is however an [article](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseEclipseLinkWithAS7) that explains how to use EclipseLink with JBoss AS 7.

I would however encourage you to use JPA as it's more portable than using vendor specific JPA implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already aware that JBoss AS7 uses Hibernation by default and did follow the steps in that article to get logging done with Slf4j. What I don't understand is why empty log messages are being logged in category org.eclipse.persistence.

Comment: So the logging message just looks something like `19:28:51,663 INFO  [org.eclipse.persistence] `?

Comment: And example (not sure why I missed timestamp in initial post): 

`13:51:31,011 WARN  [org.eclipse.persistence] (MSC service thread 1-2)`

Comment: Can you show the format pattern? In CLI you would use `/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:read-attribute(name=formatter)`

Comment: The pattern is `%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n`. But I don't see the problem with it cause it works well for all logging by JBoss, EclipseLink and my application. Only problem is `org.eclipse.persistence` logging empty lines on startup.

Comment: I was just hoping it was something missing in the pattern as that would be an easy fix :-) the pattern looks fine though. I'm really not sure why it wouldn't log the messages. I would have to debug to see what is going on.